# how to create a template based table and use it in multiple DITA xml and populate the data through it

Tags: python, dita

I am new to DITA. I would like to create the DITA xml for my PDF publishing

WHAT I WANT TO DO IS :

first i want to have the template based table which can be used in number of DITA xmls
and in hat table template I can populate the data according to my need.
In this way I can use same table schema multiple times and populate different data into that table present in different DITA xmls.

can it be possible through python?

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: In DITA specification, the table model is already defined: http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part3-all-inclusive/langRef/base/table.html#table. What is the concrete meaning of `table template`?

Comment: Do you have non-DITA table based data and want to generate DITA table automatically from them by using Python?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use the DITA `conref` capability. For the template table, you can have that in a DITA XML file that you store separately. Then in each DITA file that you want to use that table in, you use a `conref` to pull in your template table.

You could use Python for this, but it would be simpler to just use the free DITA Open Toolkit, which supports the `conref` feature by default.

Comment: `conref` does not support the needs: `In this way I can use same table schema multiple times and populate different data into that table present in different DITA xmls`. It only fetches the same table data.

Comment: yes !! by using `conref ` same table alongwith its same data get imported...

Comment: @Shubhansu If the answer above is correct, please select it as the answer.

Comment: @markg it is not correct. conref import the same data. i want to import template with different data.

Comment: @Shubhanshu Verma You can change the table with Python, then conref the table into the DITA topic. You can change the table again, and conref it into the topic again. The table must be in the correct DITA format, but you can put whatever data in it that you want.